SQL Agent Powershell Script not erroring correctly
I know that this is a common questions, but the 'fixes' I'm seeing in those questions aren't resolving my issue. The code below is being written to take backups of SSAS Cubes using the SQLServer PS Module.
The basic process is that it pulls the servers, backup location, and backup retention from a JSON file, loops through each server and then takes backups, removes old backups, etc. Think a poor mans version of Ola Hallengren scripts.
My issue is that the error handling I've tried putting in doesn't work correctly. Specifically, it seems to always be returning an exit code of 0 for success, than an exit code of 1. Yet, when I run it in a PS window, I get the results I'm expecting.
Things I've tried:

Running as both PowerShell and CMDExec mode in the SQL Agent Job.
Throw vs Write-error With and without specifying exit code
Various methods of try/catch, try/catch/finally, moving exit logic to END
block, etc.
Different EXIT methods.  You'll see them commented below
Different ways of doing ErrorActionPreference.

I'm at a loss as to why I'm not getting failures on the SQL Server Agent based upon the code below.
Appreciate any thoughts and/or ideas to get this working.
What I'm calling in the SQL Agent Job via CMDEXEC mode.  I remove the 'powershell.exe' when running SQL Agent in PowerShell Mode:
powershell.exe 'D:\dba\dba - SSAS - Take Backups\Backup_SSAS_Databases.ps1'

The actual script that's being called.
[CmdletBinding()]
param ()

BEGIN{
    Import-Module SQLServer

    #$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

    [boolean]$ErrorOccurred = $false
    [boolean]$ExitWhenFinished = $true
    [string]$LogFileName = "SSAS_Backup_log_$(GET-DATE -Format 'yyyyMMdd_HHmmss').txt"
    [string]$FileNameTemplate = "<ServerName>_<DBName>_$(get-date -Format 'yyyyMMdd_HHmmss').abf"
    [string]$ConfigFile = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Source.Replace($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name, 'SSAS_Config.json')

    if ($LogPath)
        {[String]$LogFile = "$LogPath\$LogFileName"}
    else 
        {[String]$LogFile = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Source.Replace($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name, $LogFileName)  }
    function Write-Log {
        [CmdletBinding()]
        param(
            [Parameter()]
            [ValidateNotNull()]
            [string]$Message,
     
            [Parameter()]
            [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
            [ValidateSet('INFO','WARN','EROR')]
            [string]$Severity = 'INFO',

            [Parameter()]
            [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
            [string]$Directory
        )
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Time = "[$(Get-Date -f "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")]"
            Severity = "[$Severity]"
            Message = $Message
        } | Export-Csv -Path "$Directory" -Append -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "`t"
    }

    Write-Log -Message "Let the games begin." -Severity INFO -Directory $LogFile
}
PROCESS
{
    try {
        ## Read the config file to capture the required server information.
        $SSASConfigInfo = (Get-Content -path $ConfigFile | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json)     
        Write-Log -Message "Config File: $ConfigFile" -Severity INFO -Directory $LogFile
        Write-Log -Message "Records Read : $($SSASConfigInfo.Count)" -Severity INFO -Directory $LogFile
        Write-Log -Message "Exit when finished : $ExitWhenFinished)" -Severity INFO -Directory $LogFile
        

        ## Loop through each server
        foreach ($ServerInfo in $SSASConfigInfo)
        {
            [string]$Server = $ServerInfo.SSAS_Server
            [string]$BackupFolder = $ServerInfo.BackupFolder
            [int]$RetentionInHours = $ServerInfo.Retention

            Write-Log -Message "Server:  $Server" -Severity INFO -Directory $LogFile
            Write-Log -Message "BackupPath: $BackupFolder" -Severity INFO -Directory $LogFile
            Write-Log -Message "Retention: $RetentionInHours hours."  -Severity INFO -Directory $LogFile
            Write-Log -Message "Error Occurred : $ErrorOccurred"   -Severity INFO -Directory $LogFile

            Write-Log "Starting backups of [$Server]."  -Severity INFO -Directory $LogFile
            ## Let's get the db/cube information from the SSAS Server
            try
            {
                [xml]$AllDBInfo = Invoke-ASCmd -Server $Server -Query  "<Discover xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis'><RequestType>DBSCHEMA_CATALOGS</RequestType><Restrictions /><Properties /></Discover>" -ErrorAction Stop
                $DBList = $AllDBInfo.DiscoverResponse.return.root.row.Catalog_Name
                Write-Log "DB count retrieved = $($DBList.Count)"  -Severity INFO -Directory $LogFile
            }
            catch {
                $ErrorOccurred = $true
                Write-Log "$($_.Exception.Message)" -Severity EROR -Directory $LogFile
                continue
            }
           
            foreach ($db in $DBList)
            {
                ## Let's set our vairables 
                Write-Log ""  -Severity INFO -Directory $LogFile
                Write-Log "Starting backup of [$db]."  -Severity INFO -Directory $LogFile
                $BackupFileName = $FileNameTemplate.Replace('<ServerName>', $Server)
                $BackupFileName = $BackupFileName.Replace('<DBName>', $DB)

                $BackupPath = Join-Path -Path $BackupFolder -ChildPath $Server
                $BackupPath = Join-Path -Path $BackupPath -ChildPath $db
                $BackupPath = Join-Path -Path $BackupPath -ChildPath 'SSASBackup'

                $FullBackupName = join-path -path $BackupPath -childpath $BackupFileName
                Write-Log "Backup Path: $BackupPath"  -Severity INFO -Directory $LogFile
                Write-Log "Backup Name: $BackupFileName"  -Severity INFO -Directory $LogFile
                Write-Log "Full Path  : $FullBackupName" -Severity INFO -Directory $LogFile
                
                if (test-path -path $BackupPath)
                    {Write-Log "BackupPath validated successfully."-Severity INFO -Directory $LogFile}
                else
                    {
                        Write-Log "Created the backup path: '$BackupPath'"-Severity INFO -Directory $LogFile
                        New-Item -Path $BackupPath -ItemType Directory | out-null
                    }
                
                <##############################################     Backup SSAS Cube/DB #########################################>
                try
                {
                    write-log "Backup Command:  Backup-ASDatabase -Server $Server -BackupFile $FullBackupName -Name $db -AllowOverwrite -ApplyCompression -Verbose" -Severity INFO -Directory $LogFile
                    Write-Log "Backup Start" -Severity INFO -Directory $LogFile
                    measure-command {Backup-ASDatabase -Server $Server -BackupFile $FullBackupName -Name $db -AllowOverwrite -ApplyCompression -ErrorAction Stop} -OutVariable duration | out-null
                    Write-Log "Backup Command Completed. "  -Severity INFO -Directory $LogFile
                    Write-Log "Backup Duration: $($duration.Hours) hour(s) $($duration.Minutes) minute(s) $($duration.Seconds) seconds" -Severity INFO -Directory $LogFile
                    write-log "Results: Success." -Severity INFO -Directory $LogFile
                    
                }
                catch
                {
                    ## write the error to the log file and then continue to the next cube.  Note this will also bypass the delete of the older backup, which is intended.
                    Write-Log -Message "$($Error.exception.message)" -Severity EROR -Directory $LogFile
                    Write-Log "Backup Command Completed"  -Severity INFO -Directory $LogFile
                    Write-Log "Backup Duration: $($duration.Hours) hour(s) $($duration.Minutes) minute(s) $($duration.Seconds) seconds" -Severity INFO -Directory $LogFile
                    Write-Log -Message "Result: Fail" -Severity INFO -Directory $LogFile
                    $ErrorOccurred = $true
                    continue
                }
        
                ## Let's remove older backups
                if ($RetentionInHours -gt 0)
                    {$RemoveFilesOlderThan = (get-date).AddHours($Retentioninhours * -1)}
                else 
                    {$RemoveFilesOlderThan = (get-date).AddHours($Retentioninhours)}
        
                ## Get file list
                $filesToRemove = get-childitem -Path $BackupPath | Where-Object {$_.extension -ieq '.abf' -and $_.LastWriteTime -le $RemoveFilesOlderThan}

                try 
                    {$filesToRemove  |  Remove-Item -ErrorAction Stop }
                catch {
                    ## Write the error but contiue. Shouldn't stop taking new backups if we can't remove the old ones.  
                    Write-Log -Message "$($Error.exception.message)" -Severity EROR -Directory $LogFile
                    $ErrorOccurred = $true
                    continue
                }     
                
                Write-Log "Server: [$server] completed."  -Severity INFO -Directory $LogFile
                Write-Log "" -Severity INFO -Directory $LogFile
            }
        }
    }
    catch {
        Write-Log -Message 'Primary TRY/CATCH triggered.  Error below.' -Severity EROR -Directory $LogFile
        Write-Log -Message "$($Error.exception.message)" -Severity EROR -Directory $LogFile
        Write-Log "Server [$Server] completed."  -Severity INFO -Directory $LogFile
        Write-Log "" -Severity INFO -Directory $LogFile
        $ErrorOccurred = $true
    }
    finally {
        Write-Host "Error Occurred = $ErrorOccurred"
        if ($ErrorOccurred) 
            {
                write-host 'Got inside the error block'
                Write-Verbose 'Yes, there is an error.'
                Write-Error  -Message "Error has occurred.  Log at $LogFile"   
                Exit 1
                #throw "Error has occurred.  Log at $LogFile"
                #[System.Environment]::Exit(1)
            }
        else
            {
                Write-Host 'Process completed Successfully.'
                Write-Verbose 'Nope, these are not the errors you are looking for.'
                #[System.Environment]::Exit(0)
                EXIT 0
            }
    }
}
END{
    Write-Verbose 'Got to the END segment of the code.'     
}


What version of SQL Server are you using? What version of Powershell did you test the above in?

SQL 2016 Enterprise.
PS 5.1 - both desktop and SQL Server VM.
I'll also note that when I run this on the local SQL Server PS Console, it errors as expected and I do get an $LASTEXITCODE = 1.

Was going to suggest what happens if you use #NOSQLPS but unfortunately that's no supported in 2016.

That would be nice, but not sure why that would matter if I was running in CMDEXEC mode.  When I call powershell.exe, it would run the script as PS 5.1 by default as that's the version installed on the server.

Figured out the issue.  It isn't with the script itself.  It appears to be something with how SQL is calling CMDEXEC and not handling single/double quotes...I think.  When I update SQL Agent to use the code below, it works as expected.
Originally, the entire directory and script file was in single quotes.  Now, I have double quotes around the entire string, but breaking up the internal string into a set-location and execute script.
powershell.exe "Set-Location 'D:\dba\dba - SSAS - Take Backups\'; .\Backup_SSAS_Databases.ps1;"

